# Ajax POST to Laravel API occasionally blocked by CORS

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, server, cors

Ajax POST call to my Laravel api is blocked by CORS policy, but only like 1 out of 5 times.

POST calls were blocked by CORS every time, then I've added middleware(code below) providing access control headers. Now it's weirdly getting blocked from time to time.

Js call:

```
$.post('https://myapi.com/api/posters', {somedata: 1}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
);
```

Middleware:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
      $headers = [
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin'
      ];

      $response = $next($request);
      foreach($headers as $key => $value)
          $response->header($key, $value);

      return $response;
    }
```

Note: js application is outside laravel application.
Error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Adding an CSRF token exception for this specific API in Laravel may help you to get rid of it.

Comment: I've added API path to $expect array in VerifyCsrfToken middleware, yet problem isn't gone

Comment: Follow this discussion, you may find the answer. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-avoiding-csrf-middleware-on-api-post-routes?page=1

Comment: At the times when it fails, what is the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below package to handle CORS in Laravel

```
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors
```